# AngularJS web client can't get resource from Scala Play server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala, google-chrome, coffeescript

I have an exception in my browser when I'm trying to get some data from Scala server.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/v1/animals. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
My *"CorsFilter.scala"* file:

```
package filters

import config.{ Global, WebConfig }
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.mvc.{ Filter, RequestHeader, SimpleResult }

import scala.concurrent.Future

object CorsFilter extends Filter with GlobalSettings {

  lazy val injector = Global.injector

  lazy val webConfig = injector.getInstance(classOf[WebConfig])

  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val result = next(request)
    val origin = request.headers.get("Origin")
    origin.filter(originString => originString.endsWith("animal.list") || originString == webConfig.apiDomain).map { validOrigin =>
      result.map(_.withHeaders(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> validOrigin,
        "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" -> "Server-Authorization"))(controllers.executionContext)
    }.getOrElse(result)
  }
}
```

And my function, which send the request:

```
...
  PlacesService.getAllAnimals = ->
    $http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/animals').then (result) ->
      result.data
...
```

How should I configure the server to fix my problem?

Comment: What's the content of the actual request, and response, including headers?

Comment: You do not configure methods that could be used in CORS. What is more if you are using cookies you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in response from server and client must send request with property `withCredentials: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! Added this option:

```
... ||originString.startsWith("http://localhost")).map ...
```